# iPhone Date Format Query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date

I am getting a date string back from a web service which looks like this:

```
/Date(12924576000000+0000)/
```

Can anyone tell me how to format this into a readable string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
NSString * json_parsed_date = @"/Date(12924576000000+0000)/";
NSString* tsString = [json_parsed_date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,10)];
NSNumber* timestamp = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[tsString intValue]];
NSDate * dateObject = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp intValue]];
```

For human readable string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateObject];
```